# How to change NT Service property dynamically

Tags: installshield

How it is possible to change Property of NT Service dynamically. I am using Installscript Based Project and installshield vesion is 11. I want to change NT Service property "Allow to interact with Desktop" dynamically based on certain condition.
    I have tried to write custom action whose sequence is between InstallService and StartServices. This custom action is changing registry value "Type" of service. Is it a proper solution?
    Regards
    Dev

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked if it's a "proper" solution I'll assume you are willing to listen to some advice.  Generally speaking it's a really bad idea ( nor best practice ) to create a service that can interact with the desktop.  This is especially true if the service is elevated as SYSTEM as it just open up a huge actack surface.

The generally accepted best practice is to split your UI out into it's own application such as a tray app that gets autostarted and code this UI to communicate with the service component.  An example of this would be if the service created a WCF endpoint that exposed an API.   This allows you to sandbox/firewall the elevated process and expose only those capabilities that are needed by the user.

If your development organization chooses to ignore all of this advice then form an installer perspective what you are doing will work but is not the optimal design.   A better design would be a custom action that modifies the ServiceInstall table at install time to change the value of the ServiceType column so that when InstallServices run it  is already configured correctly.